# Rsync auto detect directories with small files and compress them together for transfer

Tags: rsync

I need to transfer some files via rsync and can´t tar them before. So I thought maybe there is a mode which checks the folders content and if it is thousand of small files inside compress that folder for the transfer. However I couldn´t find something like that in the man (http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/). Is it possible and I didn´t find it or would I have to do this before I use rsync?

Comment: What do you mean by “compress them together”? Rsync will transfer them together, and it will compress them if you use the `-z` option. If you're thinking about performance, whatever tool you'd be using to “compress them together” (I guess you want to archive them together and compress the archive) would have to read all the files anyway, and that's what rsync is doing, I don't see what additional steps could make the transfer faster.

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the weaknesses of `rsync`, it just won't perform well for large numbers of small files. Why can't you use a `tar` pipe over `ssh`?

Comment: @Graeme the problem about tar is that i pull the files and don´t have write access (readonly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll typically use one of the following methods when you need to push or pull files over SSH using `tar`.

#### Copy SOURCEDIR from localhost to remotehost

Conceptually I'll often refer to this as pushing files, since we're taking the output of a `tar` command and we're pushing the files to another system over SSH. The files are targeted for copying on the remote system into `DESTDIR`.

*example 1*

```
$ tar zcvf - SOURCEDIR | ssh user1@remotehost 'cd DESTDIR; tar zxvf - '
```

*example 2*

```
$ tar zcvf - SOURCEDIR | ssh user1@remotehost "(cd DESTDIR; tar zxvf -)"
```

*example 3*

```
$ tar zcvf - SOURCEDIR | ssh -l user1 remotehost 'cd DESTDIR ; tar zxvf -'
```

#### Copy SOURCEDIR from remotehost to localhost

Conceptually I'll often refer to this as pulling files, since we're making an SSH connection to a remote host, where we're kicking off a `tar` command. The output of this `tar` command is then targeted for copying on the local system into `DESTDIR`.

*example 1*

```
$ ssh remotehost 'tar zcvf - SOURCEDIR' | tar zxvf -
```

*example 2*

```
$ ssh -n remotehost 'tar zcvf - SOURCEDIR' | tar zxvf -
```

*example 3*

```
$ ssh remotehost "( cd SOURCEDIR ; tar zcvf - SOURCEFILES ) " | tar zxvf -
```

#### References

- [Pushing & Pulling Files Around Using tar, ssh, scp, & rsync](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/1766/pushing-pulling-files-around-using-tar-ssh-scp-rsync/#more-1766)

Comment: does that work in readonly mode as pull ?

Comment: Do you mean as in a dry run mode?

Comment: well the acc I use to pull the data does not have write permission. What means dry run mode in this case?

Comment: @user2693017 - I see what you're asking. The pull method would work if the remotehost account only had read only access, since it's writing the files to the localhost side.

Comment: so does that mean the tar is generated on the fly (stored in cache)?

Comment: @user2693017 - there is no `tar` file actually created, as the contents of `tar` is created, it's redirected via the pipe, `|` to another receiving `tar` which will uncompress it.

Comment: after using this method for some time and loving it, I´m wondering if it is also possible to not extract the tar on the destdir? I tried it without tar zxvf but this didn´t work.

Comment: or that it creates a tar out of the compressed files instead of uncompressing them.

Comment: @user2693017 - from my blog post that I referenced: `tar zcvf - SOURCEDIR | ssh user1@remotehost "cat > /DESTDIR/DESTFILE.tar.gz"`.

Comment: I should have read the reference. well thanks.

Comment: @user2693017 - NP, there's always too much information to process 8-)